# Perturbation of Hamiltonian and viscosity solutions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

I am interested in the following problem.
Let $u_1$ and $u_2$ the viscosity solutions of
$$\partial_t u + H_1(t,x,u, \partial_x u) = 0 \quad \mbox{and} \quad \partial_t u + H_2(t,x,u, \partial_x u) = 0,$$
with the same initial/boundary conditions.
Of course, $H_1$ and $H_2$ are chosen so that the equations have the unique viscosity solutions.
The question is whether there is some perturbation bound, say
$$|u_1 - u_2|_{\infty} \stackrel{?}{\le} f(H_1 - H_2),$$
assuming suitable conditions on $H_1 - H_2$.
In the case where
$H_1 = H_2$ and different initial/boundary conditions, there is the maximum principle.
I wonder if there is something similar when $H_2$ is a ''perturbation" of $H_1$.
This may also be related to the weak KAM style results.
But I don't know if there is any general results there.